# SQL, querying sum of positive results, absolute value

Tags: sql

I have the following query which returns a total dollar amount.

```
select sum(cast(dollars as dec)) from financials
```

This includes positive and negative values. 
I would like 2 separate things:

1. How can I just query the positive dollar amounts?  ie. I have 3 records, 10 , -5 , 10.  result would be 20.
2. I want an absolute value as a sum.   ie. I have 3 records, 10, -5, 10. the result would be 25.

thanks.

Comment: Are you asking for two things? 1) just query the positive dollar amounts and 2) absolute value as a sum?  Give us the expected (sample) result and be more specific. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, fixed it.

Comment: 1) shouldnt be 20 instead of 15? you know 10 + 10 are the positive ones?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza , yes my mistake, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below queries. Thanks.

```
1) select sum(cast(dollars as dec)) 
from financials
where dollars > 0;

2) select sum(cast(abs(dollars) as dec)) 
from financials;
```

Answer (score 3):

FOR 1) Use conditional `SUM()`

```
SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN dollars > 0 then dollars ELSE 0 END) as positive_sum,
       SUM( CASE WHEN dollars < 0 then dollars ELSE 0 END) as negative_sum
FROM financials
```

FOR 2) use `ABS()`

```
SELECT SUM( ABS( dollars ) )
FROM financials
```

Comment: how would i fit the cast in this? I am getting error, `For 'case', types int and varchar are inconsistent`

Comment: replace `dollars` for `cast(dollars as dec)`

Answer (score 1):

You have two queries.solutions are as follows

```
1.
select sum(dollars) from financials
2. 
select sum((case when dollars>0 then dollars end))+sum((case when dollars<0 then -1*dollars end)) from financials
```